# How do I pass and receive the Sender event parameter when using Prism?

Tags: events, event-handling, prism

In typical .NET Event Handler syntax, we receive a Sender object as the first parameter:

```
Private Sub Button_Click(Sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Button.Click
End Sub
```

The value contained in this parameter can be useful for any number of scenarios.

When using the Prism Event Aggregator, however, no such Sender parameter seems to exist. Thus we don't seem to be able to know which/what/who raised the event.

Is there a way to send/receive the Sender when using Prism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the sender in the payload:

```
public class MyPayload
{
    public MyPayLoad( object sender, SomeType someData )
    {
        Sender = sender;
        SomeData = someData;
    }

    public object Sender { get; }
    public SomeType SomeData { get; }
}

eventAggregator.GetEvent<MyEvent>().Publish( new MyPayload( this, myData ) );
```

I'd use something more specific than `object` for the sender in a real app, though.